# How to downgrade package using Tex live in windows?

Tags: packages, texlive, windows

I am using my university Latex template but, it doesn't show page number and some other problems. when I ask the template publisher he said that following are required:

```
xepersian v18.8
bidi v30.8
```

I have check packages using tex live:

```
xepersian v19
bidi v31
```

So how can I downgrade packages and install the missing ones?

PS: My OS is windows 7.

Comment: @daleif, I have created a new question and remove the old ones.

Comment: getting the template updated seems like a better solution than downgrading the packages.  If you showed an example, someone could probably suggest a suitable patch.

Comment: In the case I want to downgrade these packages what can I do?

Comment: there is no general mechanism. you would need to get old versions (you may or may not have kept backups of old versions depending on your options when installing texlive) and then you would need to arrange your texinput to use the local old versions.

Comment: could you explain how to do this? How can I check whether I have an older version or not? I have installed it months ago.

Comment: see `texdoc tlmgr` and the `restore` option, but it is _such_ a weird thing to do, in 30 years of tex usage I don't think I have ever used `tlmgr restore`

Comment: I try `tlmgr restore` but nothing is shown as available version, what can I do then?

Comment: you would need to look to see if the packages you want have public version control systems and older versions are available.  As I said at the beginning there is no general way to roll back an arbitrary package to an arbitrary older version, perhaps you could look on ctan via the internet archive to find old versions. Really you do not want to do this. If your template works with version 18.8 it will work with version 19 with at most a couple of compatibility definitions. If you showed the error messages you were getting someone could help.

Comment: It compiles fine but there are some problem: 1- page numbers not shown in pdf 2- line space problem in my dictionary part which are related to template

Comment: You will have warnings, most probably. Certainly info. But code we can compile to reproduce the problem, including a link to the template if appropriate, would be best.

Comment: I have updated all packages page number problem is solved but the line spacing in glossary is different in Persian and English glossary. here is the way it created: `{\cleardoublepage\setlength{\baselineskip}{1cm}\printpersianglossary\cleardoublepage\printenglishglossary}`